# Core data delete single record from to many relation ship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have created 4 entities.
User, Mobile, Email, Address.
User have to many relationship (name as numbers) with Mobile.
I have subclass for all of above. How to delete single mobile number from particular user? How to update single mobile number from particular user?,what Predicate use for that?

code is here:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([User class])]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY numbers.number == %@",self.textField.text]; 
[request setPredicate:predicate];
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; Mobile *objMobile;
 User *objUser; 
objUser = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    for (User *obj in [objUser.numbers valueForKey:@"number"]) { 

NSLog(@"%@",obj);
 NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];
 NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.textDelete.text];

 if ([str1 isEqualToString:str2] ) { 
[objUser removeNumbersObject:objMobile]; } 
}
 NSLog(@"%@",[objUser.numbers valueForKey:@"number"]); self.textAddUserDetail.text = @"";
 if (![context save:&error]) { }
```

Comment: why do you need a predicate? show the code you tried and explain what goes wrong with it.

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([User class])];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY numbers.number ==  %@",self.textField.text];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    Mobile *objMobile;
    User *objUser;
    objUser = [array objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: for (User *obj in [objUser.numbers valueForKey:@"number"])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",obj);
            NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];
            NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.textDelete.text];
            if ([str1 isEqualToString:str2] )
            {
                [objUser removeNumbersObject:objMobile];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",[objUser.numbers valueForKey:@"number"]);
        self.textAddUserDetail.text = @"";
        
        if (![context save:&error])
        {
            
        }

Comment: please always edit your question, code is unreadable in comments

Comment: so you're trying to search for a number to edit?

Comment: ya i want that number to delete.

Comment: and also update a particular mobile number also.

Comment: What is the delete rule for the Mobile->User relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, don't search based on the user and the relationship. Instead, search directly for the number and then delete it or edit it:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Number class])]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number == %@", self.textField.text];
```

Then you also don't need a loop and extra consideration of what to do.

Comment: Thanks. how to update that particular mobile number.

Comment: do you understand what classes and instances are?

Comment: ya i have created subclasses of NSManagedObject for User, Mobile, Address, Email.

Comment: so you know about setting values on those instances, and about saving the context

Comment: ya. i do . but it will work for update too(i afraid because it is in relation ship).

Comment: try it out and see

Answer (score 0):

It will be useful to use "Magical Records" Library.it work with Key value coding need not to maintain Relationships.it will Automatically get the unique Key From all the Entitys